# Background threading not working whilst adding overlay

Tags: c#, ios, .net, multithreading, xamarin

I am trying to add a loading overlay whilst my app makes a call to to web api service in a background thread but for some reason it doesnt work. When i use the following code, it works as expected:

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew (

            () => {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Hello from taskA." );
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }

        ).ContinueWith ( 
            t => {
                loadingOverlay.Hide();

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );
```

The above code writes into the console and then sleeps for 3 seconds as expected and then removes the overlay. However, when i add a call into the repository, it skips the entire first section and just hides the overlay.

The new code looks like this:

```
          Task.Factory.StartNew (

            () => {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Hello from taskA." );
                var user = userRepository.GetUserByEmail(EmailTextBox.Text);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            ).ContinueWith ( 
            t => {
                loadingOverlay.Hide();

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );


    };
```

The code in the repository is as follows:

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient ()) {
   client.BaseAddress = _uri;
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear ();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue ("application/json"));
     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(String.Format("GetUser?email={0}", email)).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

            var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User> (jsonResponse);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps there's an exception which you're missing because nowhere do you wait for the task to finish using `Task.Wait()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the await & async keywords.

```
var user = await userRepository.GetUserByEmail(EmailTextBox.Text);
loadingOverlay.Hide();
```

The await keyword just mean you wait an answer from GetUserByEmail before excuting the next code line.

you need to do the same for this line instead of **.Result**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("GetUser?email={0}", email));
```

Don't forget to put the async keyword on you web call method.

With this await keyword, you need to put async in your method who use the await keyword.

more about async & await : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: great ! just put my answer in acceptance, this will help other people to get quickly a reply to a similar problem.